# Resolver Captchas Con 2Captcha Con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Necesito Hacer La Siguiente Petición Para Resolver Captchas Con La Pagina 2Captcha Si Me Puedieran Hacer El Favor De Guiarme Como Se Hace Se Los Agradesco Dejo A continuación Lo Que Me Dice La Pagina.

4. Envíe una solicitud HTTP GET o POST a nuestra URL de API: https://2captcha.com/in.phpcon el método establecido en userrecaptcha y proporcione el valor encontrado en el paso anterior como valor para googlekey y URL de página completa como valor para pageurl.
5. Si todo está bien, el servidor devolverá la ID de su captcha como texto sin formato, como: OK | 2122988149 o como JSON {"status": 1, "request": "2122988149"} si se utilizó el parámetro json .
   De lo contrario, el servidor devolverá un código de error .
6. Haga un tiempo de espera de 15-20 segundos y luego envíe una solicitud HTTP GET a nuestra URL de API: https://2captcha.com/res.phppara obtener el resultado.
   Si captcha ya está resuelto, el servidor responderá en texto plano o JSON y devolverá el token de respuesta que se ve así:

"03AHJ_Vuve5Asa4koK3KSMyUkCq0vUFCR5Im4CwB7PzO3dCxIo11i53epEraq-uBO5mVm2XRikL8iKOWr0aG50sCuej9bXx5qcviUGSm4iK4NC_Q88flavWhaTXSh0VxoihBwBjXxwXuJZ-WGN5Sy4dtUl2wbpMqAj8Zwup1vyCaQJWFvRjYGWJ_TQBKTXNB5CCOgncqLetmJ6B6Cos7qoQyaB8ZzBOTGf5KSP6e-K9niYs772f53Oof6aJeSUDNjiKG9gN3FTrdwKwdnAwEYX-F37sI_vLB1Zs8NQo0PObHYy0b0sf7WSLkzzcIgW9GR0FwcCCm1P8lB-50GQHPEBJUHNnhJyDzwRoRAkVzrf7UkV8wKCdTwrrWqiYDgbrzURfHc2ESsp020MicJTasSiXmNRgryt-gf50q5BMkiRH7osm4DoUgsjc_XyQiEmQmxl5sqZP7aKsaE-EM00x59XsPzD3m3YI6SRCFRUevSyumBd7KmXE8VuzIO9lgnnbka4-eZynZa6vbB9cO3QjLH0xSG3-egcplD1uLGh79wC34RF49Ui3eHwua4S9XHpH6YBe7gXzz6_mv-o-fxrOuphwfrtwvvi2FGfpTexWvxhqWICMFTTjFBCEGEgj7_IFWEKirXW2RTZCVF0Gid7EtIsoEeZkPbrcUISGmgtiJkJ_KojuKwImF0G0CsTlxYTOU2sPsd5o1JDt65wGniQR2IZufnPbbK76Yh_KI2DY4cUxMfcb2fAXcFMc9dcpHg6f9wBXhUtFYTu6pi5LhhGuhpkiGcv6vWYNxMrpWJW_pV7q8mPilwkAP-zw5MJxkgijl2wDMpM-UUQ_k37FVtf-ndbQAIPG7S469doZMmb5IZYgvcB4ojqCW3Vz6Q"

Si captcha no se resuelve, el servidor devolverá el resultado CAPCHA_NOT_READY . Repita su solicitud en 5 segundos.

Si algo salió mal, el servidor devolverá un código de error .

7. Localice el elemento con id g-recaptcha-response y hágalo visible eliminando la pantalla: ninguno de los parámetros.

Como alternativa, puede usar javascript para establecer el valor del campo g-recaptcha-response:

document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML="TOKEN_FROM_2CAPTCHA";

Aparecerá un campo de entrada en la página. Y solo tiene que pegar el token de respuesta en ese campo y enviar el formulario.

Agradesco Quien Me Pueda Guiar Y si Depronto Alguien Ya Lo Realizo En C#